# How to Develop a captcha using jsf

Tags: jsf-2

Can somebody give me the steps and explain how can I can develop a captcha using jsf for my web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already available out of box in [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/captcha.xhtml) library.